# Javascript Pacman-style Game - not able to store scores in horizontal path

Tags: javascript

I'm doing this exercise with JavaScript and we're supposed to create a ninja pacman-style game with Javascript and then keep score. The ninja eats sushis and I'm doing one point per sushi.

The current behavior is that I can store scores when the ninja goes up or down. Problem is that when the ninja moves horizontally, the score only counts the first sushi. Second and third sushis aren't counted. I did use the same logic for vertical and horizontal moving around.

Here is my code. Added the whole code for context, but the problematic part is after "document.onkeydown = function(e) {".

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var world = [
    [1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,2,2,1],
    [1,2,1,2,1],
    [3,2,2,2,3],
    [1,2,1,2,1],
    [1,2,2,2,1],
    [3,2,1,2,3],
    [1,2,2,2,1],
    [1,1,1,3,1],
]

var worldDict = {
    0 : 'blank',
    1 : 'wall',
    2 : 'sushi',
    3 : 'onigiri'

}

var ninjaScore = 0;

function drawWorld() {
    var output = "";

    for (var row = 0; row < world.length; row++) {
        output += "<div class='row'></div>"
        for (var x = 0; x <world[row].length; x++) {
            output += "<div class='" + worldDict[world[row][x]]+"'></div>"

        }
        output += "</div>"
    }

    document.getElementById('world').innerHTML = output;

}

drawWorld();

var ninjaman = {
    x: 1,
    y: 1
}

function drawNinjaMan() {
    document.getElementById('ninjaman').style.top = ninjaman.y * 40 + "px"
    document.getElementById('ninjaman').style.left = ninjaman.x * 40 + "px"
}

drawNinjaMan();

document.onkeydown = function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 40) { //DOWN
        if (world[ninjaman.y + 1][ninjaman.x] != 1) {
            ninjaman.y++;
            if (world[ninjaman.y + 1][ninjaman.x] == 2) { //Checking if next block is sushi; adding to score
                ninjaScore = ninjaScore + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 38) { //UP
        if (world[ninjaman.y - 1][ninjaman.x] != 1) {
            ninjaman.y--;
            if (world[ninjaman.y - 1][ninjaman.x] == 2) { //Checking if next block is sushi; adding to score
                ninjaScore = ninjaScore + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 37) { //LEFT
        if (world[ninjaman.y][ninjaman.x - 1] != 1) {
            ninjaman.x--;
            if (world[ninjaman.y][ninjaman.x - 1] == 2) { //Checking if next block is sushi; adding to score
            //Somehow this is returning false on the second key press; need to check why
                ninjaScore = ninjaScore + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 39) { //RIGHT
        if (world[ninjaman.y][ninjaman.x + 1] != 1) {
            ninjaman.x++;
            if (world[ninjaman.y][ninjaman.x + 1] == 2) { //Checking if next block is sushi; adding to score
            //Somehow this is returning false on the second key press; need to check why
                ninjaScore = ninjaScore + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    world[ninjaman.y][ninjaman.x] = 0;
    drawWorld()
    drawNinjaMan()
}
```

Could anyone please point out what I'm getting wrong?

Also, to give credit: This is an exercise from the pre-bootcamp course at Coding Dojo (https://www.codingdojo.com/). They came up with most of the code and the exercise itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you're moving the ninja on top of a sushi, and then checking the block ahead of the block you are on in the direction you are moving. And all your motions are wrong, up, down, left and right.

This should fix it.
https://plnkr.co/edit/VCsa2cTWYaUn2jiTgmS4?p=preview

```
if (world[ninjaman.y][ninjaman.x-1] == 2) { //Checking if
```

should be

```
if (world[ninjaman.y][ninjaman.x] == 2) { //Checking if
```

Comment: Done! Thank you so much :)